# How to identity duplicate user accounts on a website?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

In a website where policy restricts multiple account creations or a suspended user which is permanently banned from the site is restricted creating new user accounts.

on back-end is there a way to find duplicate accounts?

Can this be done with IP addresses or with cookies?

Comment: Nope. (1) You can't distinguish whether the same person or different people are creating multiple accounts from the same computer/address. (2) You can't distinguish whether the same person or different people are creating multiple accounts from different computers/addresses. How would it be possible?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm interesting question

```
request.remote_ip
```

in your controller should give you the clients IP address which you can then save for later validation. You should be REALLY careful if you're storing lots of IP addresses though and it doesn't remove the problem if the person were to change computers

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No, that's not possible.

All you can do is

1. collect/store information about registered users, browsers, IP etc.
2. use cookies and/or local storage to track a unique user hash.

If you combine both and filter accounts based on some more or less strict rules (whatever fits your needs), you will be able to identify some duplicate accounts for sure, but it is by far not 100% safe.